# Como Chamar valores de Outra Classe

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, hibernate

Estou criando um controle de veículos, e nele tenho um cadastro de Combustível que possui descrição e valor, e outro cadastro de Abastecimentos. No meu cadastro de abastecimentos tem um `autoComplete` de Combustível. O problema começa aqui, quando eu seleciono o combustível eu preciso chamar o valor de custo que está cadastrado neste combustível.

Exemplo: Selecionei Diesel.

```
TOTAL = Valor * LitrosAbastecidos.
```

Porém a variável `Valor` está dentro da classe Combustível.
Alguém teria alguma forma simples de resolver isso?

Obs.: Sistema feito em Java, Hibernate, JSF

Chama o Combustivel

```
<p:autoComplete id="combustivel" value="#{abastecimentoControle.abastecimento.combustivel}" completeMethod="#{combustivelControle.listaFiltrando}"
                                       converter="#{combustivelControle.combustivelConverter}"
                                       var="c"
                                       disabled="true"
                                       itemValue="#{c}"
                                       itemLabel="#{c.descricao}"/>
```

Meu Lista Filtrando

```
public List<Combustivel> listaFiltrando(String parte){
    System.out.println("Parte: "+parte);
    return combustivelFacade.listaFiltrando(parte);
}
```

Comment: Como você esta fazendo isso? select no banco ? em uma lista no java? tente editar sua pergunta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Editei cara, se precisar de mais algum detalhe eu coloco tb

Comment: Achei sua pergunta um tanto confusa. Não consegui entender exatamente o que é que você está pedindo ou o que é que está tentando fazer. Talvez se você der mais detalhes sobre a classe `Combustivel`, fique melhor para entender.

Comment: Minha classe combustível tem: Id, descrição e valor. No meu abastecimento vou ter que selecionar o combustível pegar o valor deste combustível selecionado e fazer a conta. Minha dificuldade é como pegar o valor do combustível selecionado.

Comment: Você poderia implementar uma chamada via ajax no método "onChange" do seu campo e buscar o combustível do objeto selecionado...

Comment: Como faria isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leandro, quando você chama o combustível aparentemente você seta o atributo combustivel do objeto abastecimento que é um atributo do objeto abastecimentoControle:

```
value="#{abastecimentoControle.abastecimento.combustivel}"
```

Então eu faria assim dentro da classe abastecimentoControle:

```
Double total = this.getAbastecimento().getCombustivel().getValor() * litrosAbastecidos
```

Comment: Sim, deu pra entender, mais como faria pra pegar o combustível que o usuário selecionou ? Isso que não consegui entender

Comment: Quando você digita o combustível no input autocomplete, o atributo: value="#{abastecimentoControle.abastecimento.combustivel}" recebe o valor selecionado da lista: completeMethod="#{combustivelControle.listaFiltrando}"

Comment: Desculpe-me, acabei dando enter antes de completar o comentário... É o seguinte: o componente primefaces autocomplete recebe a lista de objetos do dao através de: completeMethod="#{combustivelControle.listaFiltrando}" e usa esta lista para autocompletar o input quando você digita algo, ao mesmo tempo que seta o atributo: "#{abastecimentoControle.abastecimento.combustivel}" do seu controler, então o seu controler possui o combustível selecionado neste atributo...

Comment: Entendi, mais como vou pegar o valor ? Desculpa sou novo no assunto rs esse é meu listaFiltrando 
  public List<Combustivel> listaFiltrando(String parte){
        System.out.println("Parte: "+parte);
        return combustivelFacade.listaFiltrando(parte);
    }

Comment: Acredito que o retorno do método(return combustivelFacade.listaFiltrando(parte);) retorne uma lista de objetos do dao(correto?) então quando você digita o combustível no input o valor submetido ao controller(value="#{abastecimentoControle.abastecimento.combustivel}") é na verdade o objeto combustível da lista que veio do dao, quem faz isso é o componente, talvez você tenha que colocar um botão ou usar ajax para submeter(setar) o valor no controller, só consigo pensar isto com as informações que você passou, talvez se visse o dao, o converter e a tela com mais detalhes daria pra te ajudar mais

Comment: Cara consegui muito obrigado, suas dicas me ajudaram muito

Comment: Que bom, fico contente, boa sorte!!